# How to manage a DNS server remotely?

Tags: dns, bind

I whant to make a web interface on a server that will manage a few dns servers on another servers.

#### How can i remotely manage a bind dns server programmaticly ?

- I would like to add/edit/delete zones.
- I see that there is rndc but that only allows reloading of zones and not adding/deleting.
- I could NFS mount zones from dns servers and edit them but is there a better way?

Comment: Later versions of ISC bind have "rndc addzone" and kin.

Personally we just use a script to dump zone configs from SQL into a bind config, and include this in our main config.

Comment: see http://serverfault.com/questions/10686/what-is-the-best-webinterface-to-manage-bind

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If there isn't a hard requirement on writing something like this from scratch, why not simply use an already existing interface without having to reinvent the wheel? A simple [Google search for the keywords bind dns web interface](http://www.google.com/search?q=bind+dns+web+interface) yields an entire list of good open source projects in the very first result link.

Comment: yes but don't those software require that bind runs on the same server as the software?

Comment: Not all. mysqlBind doesn't require it. It was mentioned on the very first result page.

Comment: Yeah, don't reinvent the wheel. Good answer!

Comment: One question about the mysqlbind will it hit the database for each request or only on reload it reads the zones and the caches them?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. If you're asking whether any DNS lookup will cause a MySQL database hit, then no, of course not - unless you've built your nameserver with a MySQL backend, in which case you'd incur that hit anyway, without needing mysqlBind :)

Comment: Great, thanks. That's what I was referring to. Sorry I wasn't clear. I think I'll go with PostgreSQL-BIND instead of mysql one though. Thanks again.

Comment: Sure, just use whatever you're most familiar with - but please test the hell out of it first :).

Answer (score 3):

There is work at the IETF to define a standard for remote control of name servers based on the Netconf framework.  See:

- https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-dnsop-name-server-management-reqs
- https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-dickinson-dnsop-nameserver-control-00.txt

The requirements include the ability to add/remove zones, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You could set up something that does remote SSH commands? That may be a bit insecure, though, unless the server running the commands themselves is pre-authenticated with an SSH key, and that's the only way you can access the server.